# Using Javascript, I would like to pick up any content in a form field if a user clicks a non-form element

Tags: javascript

I have a login form on an application that we cannot change the back-end of (vendor supplied), but we can change the template (ie: the html and javascript).  It has a "forgot password" link below it.  Almost all users will just click the link, but some put in their username, try a few iterations and then hit the "forgot password" link.

What I would like to do is use javascript to take a look at the username field and, if it has any content, change the URL of the "forgot password" link to point to the next step in the password recovery.

So, when the user clicks on the link with no value in the username field, the link goes to: http://example.com/system/lookup.html

If there is a value in the username field, I'd like the link to resolve to:
http://example.com/system/lookup.html?id={username}

Easy to do?

Comment: I'd tie the onchange event to the username field and then if there's content, alter the link.

Answer (score 0):

try listening to the input's change event or key down and then change the link

jQUery

```
$('.selector').change(function(){
$('a#forgot').attr('href','your html address here').html('The text displayed here')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, easy to do:

1. In your markup leave the link's `href` as the first url so that if the user has JS turned off it will still work for them.
2. Add an `onclick` handler to the link that checks the value of the username field and if it is not blank change the `href` of the link.

Code:

```
window.onload = function() {
   var link = document.getElementById("yourLinkId");
   link.onclick = function() {
      var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
      if (username != "") {
          link.href = "http://example.com/system/lookup.html?id=" +
                      encodeURIComponent(username);
      }
   };
};
```

Your link and username fields will need to have `id` set to match what you use in the JS.

Comment: I like this method, but I get the following URL whether there is something in the form-field or not: http://example.com/system/lookup.html?id=[object%20HTMLInputElement]

Comment: Ah, looks like the code has been updated: var username = document.getElementById("username").value; works

Comment: Yeah, sorry, just after I hit the submit button I realised I'd left the `.value` off so I quickly edited it in hoping nobody would notice. (Note that you might want to add an `else` case to (re)set the default url in case the user presses the browser's stop button and clears out the username field. Alternatively remove the `if` altogether and then test server-side whether the `id` parameter was blank.)

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the value of the input and check it against a length or a value.

Depending on the value, you can change out the URL

See fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Z3VXr/3/